# Removing extra characters from name of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

iv'e got an problem with extra characters in names of checkboxes.

There is a line

```
var string = "<div class="blblb"><input type="checkbox" name="dasdasads"><input type="checbox" name="adsdsada"></div>";
```

The question is, how to remove if exist extra characters from ,,string,, but only from names of checkboxes ? Characters like `"` and `'`

I'm looking on google and I can't find anything.

Comment: What extra characters? The string above is invalid, you need to escape the quotes (guessing that is what the question is.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "<div class=\"blblb\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"dasdasads\"><input type=\"checbox\" name=\"adsdsada\"></div>";
```

escape those by using `\`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('name',$(this).attr('name').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/'/g,""));
})
```

Comment: I need to do something like 

var string = 'blablabla';
str.replace(string) etc.

Not onlny editing HTML

Answer (score 0):

I've gon an builder system, and inputs where i put a names of checboxes, but if i will put " or ' in name attr whole system is down.

var string has a whole HTML code . And in this code are checkboxes, 5-10 checboxes.

I need to remove if exist extra characters from checkboxe's names.

Ps. I can't rebuild anything in builder.

This string is uploaded to database, i need to remove chars when system is loading and displaying it.

```
disphmtl = disphmtl + decodeURIComponent(item.offerdetails.htmnl) + '</div></form><article>' +
```